# Multithreading in C# calling another software

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to programming and to multithreading.  It is not my field, so patience and thorough answer are much appreciated. 
I am using Parallel.for to perform the calculations where the results are calculated using a simulation software. 
I am facing two problems. The first is when calling multiple instances of the simulation software, the first instance will start. However, I will get an error for trying to starting the second instance. I was able to work around it by delaying the start of the second instance.  It is working but it is not ideal. 
The second problem occurs when the second instance starts, the first instance will stop and the second instance will preform couple of simulations before it crashes. I am getting a bunch of exceptions thrown by the application.

```
object GetStrobo()
    {    
        try
        {
            if (StroboApp == null)
            {
               igh = igh + 1;
               if (igh == 1)
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(10000);
               }
           objDocType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Stroboscope.Document");
           StroboApp = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objDocType);
        }      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            StroboApp = null;
        }
        return StroboApp;
    }

public void testStroboRun()
    {
       GetStrobo();
       int nResult;
       StreamReader abc = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\iju\1.txt"); 
       string ConCode = abc;

        try
        {
           objDocType.InvokeMember("ClientVersion", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
           null, StroboApp, new object[] { "test Strobo" });

            nResult = int.Parse(objDocType.InvokeMember("RunStatements", 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, StroboApp,
             new object[] { ConCode }).ToString());

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            nResult = -1;
            if (nResult != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

public void run()
    {
        Parallel.For(1, 3500,  new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, index =>
      {
             testStroboRun(); });
      }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

The exception I am getting for creating two instances of a software at the same time is

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type   
'Stroboscope.CStroboAutomDoc'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM 
component for the interface with IID '{0116EC76-96E4-11CE-AF55-524153480002}' failed due to the 
following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 
(E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

The other exceptions I am getting are related to Parallel.For. The source is mscorlib and the message is

```
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken  
cancellationToken)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, 
ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, 
Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions 
parallelOptions, Action`1 body)

at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)

at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[]  
args)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()

at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback 
callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback 
callback, Object state)

at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()"
```

The new code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Stroboscope;

namespace Sample
{
 class Program
 {
    public double x1;
    public static object StroboApp;
    public static System.Type objDocType;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program _Sample = new Program();
        _Sample.run();
    }

    static object GetStrobo()
    {
        if (StroboApp == null)
        {
            objDocType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Stroboscope.Document");
            StroboApp = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objDocType);
        }
        return StroboApp;
    }

    public void testStroboRun()
    {
        GetStrobo();
        int nResult;
        StreamReader abc = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\1.str");
        String strFile = abc.ReadToEnd();
        strFile = Regex.Replace(strFile, "x1", "" + x1);
        string ConCode = strFile;
        objDocType.InvokeMember("ClientVersion", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,  
        null, StroboApp, new object[] { "test Strobo" });
        nResult = int.Parse(objDocType.InvokeMember("RunStatements", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, StroboApp,
        new object[] { ConCode }).ToString());
        objDocType.InvokeMember("EndModel", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, 
        StroboApp, null);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int yth = 1; yth < 100; yth++)
        {
            x1 = rnd.Next(1, 20);
            testStroboRun();
        }}}}
```

Comment: You are asking us to debug you program, to get awnsers you should be more specific on what your problem is and post it with the minimal code and exceptions you are not understanding. For example your requirement of delaying your program is not working correct.

Comment: I thought I described my problem clearly. I am getting several exceptions which i added and minimized the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what stroboscope is but i think you've (probably wrongly) diagnosed this as a threading problem (it may or may not be, but it definately sounds like the issue is either in the stroboscope api or simply that stroboscope doesn't support multiple threads calling into it).

Your first error is clear, it's complaining within stroboscope.

Your second error may be less clear, but it simply indicates where the exception ran, deeply Inside .net within the for method, but this simply hints at your code crashing in there (it's the System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker method that will execute your code, and it's crashing there).

debugging this is easy

Remove the parallel.for and replace it with a plain for, does it still crash? If yes then your code is likely wrong (the way you're calling the API, nothing to do with multithreading). If not then it most likely means their API doesn't support getting called from multiple threads and there's not much you can do about it

Edit : as requested you'll find a sample bellow with some improvements, it's untested as i don't have stroboscope :

```
class Program
{
    public static System.Type objDocType;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // create the randoms beforehand as rnd.Next() isn't thread safe so we don't want to call it within the parallel.for later down the road
        var randoms = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
            .Select(i => rnd.Next())
            .ToArray();            

        // Sequential version
        for (int yth = 1; yth < 100; yth++)
        {
            testStroboRun(randoms[yth]);
        }
        // Parallel version
        Parallel.For(1, 100, yth => 
        {
            testStroboRun(randoms[yth]);
        });
    }

    static object GetStrobo()
    {
        // Create the object here and return it, do not store it in a global variable that each thread will access, each thread needs to get his own instance, so each call should return a new instance to be used only by the calling thread
        objDocType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Stroboscope.Document");
        return System.Activator.CreateInstance(objDocType);
    }

    static void testStroboRun(int x1)
    {
        // Removed empty variable declarations, don't declare a variable before assining it, it's redundant.

        // You don't need to use a streamreader to read a text file by calling ReadToEnd, you can directly use File.ReadAllText to get your string
        //StreamReader abc = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\1.str");
        //String strFile = abc.ReadToEnd();

        var strFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\1.str");            
        strFile = Regex.Replace(strFile, "x1", "" + x1);

        // Why do you create that ConCode variable? you're just reusing strFile and doing nothing new with either strFile or ConCode later on, just pass strFile later down instead
        //string ConCode = strFile;
        var StroboApp = GetStrobo();
        objDocType.InvokeMember("ClientVersion", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, StroboApp, new object[] { "test Strobo" });
        int nResult = int.Parse(objDocType.InvokeMember("RunStatements", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, StroboApp, new object[] { strFile }).ToString());
        objDocType.InvokeMember("EndModel", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, StroboApp, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The first error is for sure with creating multiple instances simultaneously. I was able to work around with delaying the start of the second instance.                           The second error only happens when I use Parallel.For. If I use for by itself, everything works fine. I know that Stroboscope can work in parallel since I was able to call it from an algorithm (black box) that perform parallel programming using MPI. However, running MPI on a single machine doesn't take advantage of the physical threads and I noticed that it increases the overhead.

Comment: If it's not using multiple physical threads, it's not working in parallel but simply in an asychronous fashion. So it doesn't give the performance benefit of parallelism but it doesn't give some of the issues either. Do you have any documentation that lead you to believe that StroboApp's type is thread safe? If not the default assumption for , well pretty much everything, is that it's not. Things have to be programmed explicitely to be thread safe so unless they did, don't expect to be able to call methods on the same application from multiple threads.

Comment: Also what's with the igh counter and the thread.sleep? Sounds like you're likely creating multiple instances there since multiple threads could be within getstrobo at the same time and match the null condition.

Comment: Did you check that you're not actually creating multiple instances of the application because of that? If you don't want to bother with multithreading concepts to lock it properly during initialisation, why not just initialise the app before your parallel.for loop and expose that as a property?

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation of the software that says anything about parallel execution. The other black box algorithm can use StroboApp in parallel but it was designed for physical cores and multiprocessor machines. If I am using a quad-core machine, the black box can run 4 instances in parallel. But I want to make it to run 8 instances in parallel one for each logical core. That is possible, right?

Comment: The igh counter is just used to delay the start of the second instance. They both match the null condition at the beginning but one instance will into  Thread.sleep() and the other will start StroboApp.

Comment: StroboApp is used to calculate the value of my function and therefore multiple instances should exist to perform parallel computation. For that reason, it should be initialized in Parallel.For loop

Comment: You're mixing a lot of things here. There are no diferences between physical cores or even having a single cores, this doesn't relate to threads, you can run 100 threads on a single core if you want, Windows will Schedule them as it see fits (so the more cors / processor, the merrier).

Comment: You're not delaying anything, both instances could start stroboapp as there is no locking, in multithreading anytime you're using thread.Sleep, you're doing something wrong. There could be a race condition and both could get to the check before increment happens, so both could bypass the check and create the app

Comment: you're saying multiple instances should exist, you're not creating multiple instances since you're using the same variable and only initializing it once, just return the instance instead of having a global variable for it and create 1 instance per thread, all your issues should be fixed, don't try to "share" the stroboapp across threads.

Comment: Thanks again for your patience and explanation.. You are right, you can run as many threads as you want and Windows will schedule them but I read in several places that the optimum is one thread per core.. and you are right about both instances starting the app at the same time

Comment: I might be asking too much but could you please show me how to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: I can show you a sample but please post your full program in a compile ready way then so i can fix it for you, it's hard to do with your example, also remove all the needless try/catch, make it a minimalistic and non multithreaded sample that works for you, and i'll turn it into a multi instance version after you do that

Comment: Thanks again.. The code I added above is compile ready and working perfectly for me.

Comment: Ok that whole program makes no sense to parallelise as is which is your core issue, you keep stuffing things into shared variables, so you only have 1 "x1" and 1 "StroboApp", the later isn't thread safe so you get crashes and your x1 is completely random since multiple thread run at once you could well get the same value for plenty of them.

Comment: I'm writing an updated sample as an answer now but, and please take no offense in this, you really shouldn't be tackling with multithreading as your code, even as a single thread, is full of antipaterns, like calling a method (which could just be a getter) to initialise a shared variable which it already returns, and is never accessed by it's (then useless return value) but instead by the shared object.

Comment: Also this is out of the scope of your question but i'm pretty sure you could use this a lot more cleanly with com interop instead of using reflection and createinstance you should be able to import the types from (i assume this is a com Library?) a tbl file or something similar

Comment: Thank you for the sample and for the hints. None taken, as I mentioned I am new to programming and I appreciate your patience.  The way you defined StroboApp will return an instance of Stroboscope for every increment in the for loop (i.e., 100). Ideally, if the degreeofparallelism is 2, only 2 instances will be created and each instance will evaluate 50 random numbers. It is like starting visual studio, open a new project, run the project (RunStatement), then close the project (EndModel) without closing visual studio.

Comment: Yes, I do have a tlb file and dll file. I will look into com interop and how to use it. I am travelling tomorrow and I won't be able to reply before Thursday. Thanks again

Comment: @Newbie82 Don't forget to mark my answer as the answer if it answered your original question (this is a Q&A site, i can't continually provide more help in comments as it's not suited to the site format and your question thus changes as you make progress, you need to figure this out and do some of the work or to create another new question)

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I am trying to figure how to control the software using com interop. Thanks for you help so far.